# Flutter Facebook Login Implementation Wrong Key Hash

Tags: facebook, flutter, hash, flutter-layout

I've downloaded the openssl and added it in my environment.
When I try to generate a key hash using:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias key -keystore "C:\Users\Claude\.android\debug.keystore" | D:\Documents\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | D:\Documents\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl base64
```

But it produces this : `Pz8/ERApRXg/Pz8/Pyk/RT8/Px8K`

I've navigated to where my keytool is and rerun the command but still the same.

I've delete the old key and generated another and then rerun the command but still the same.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the **debug.keystore** present at the location of your system, "C:\Users\Claude.android\debug.keystore"

Then generate debug hash key using the command,

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

generate debug hash key using the command after you have generated key store,

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```